# Fire an event even if browser is closed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am currently programming with PHP/HTML/CSS/MYSQL/JAVASCRIPT and i want to perform the following scenario:

Send an email to someone but not by clicking a button "SEND".

I want to build something called "Future Send" that will enable the user to schedule when the email will be send. (for example 5 minutes from now).

This is easy to be accomplished with a Javascript counter that will fire an event when countdown == 0; But this requires that the browser/website must be open.

But what happens in the event that the user writes the email, schedule it for 5 minutes later, and closes the browser or even the computer? The counter will stop and the event will never be fired..

Is there a way to bypass this using the technologies referred above?

Do i have to switch to a different programming language?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Store information to mysql. Use a cronjob to read data and send email.

Comment: That is what i thought,, Just a question: If i set the cron job to run every 10 seconds what will be the impact on the server (if any)?

Comment: @christostsang - Using cron, you can only run a task every minute. It shouldn't have much impact on the server - you're going to be doing a database query (to get the emails to sent), a little processing, and some emailing. You can run the code from the command line before you start to see how much load it creates.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar case in my production and i made as follow :
1- store the subject, cc, rc, body in a text file
2- name it as follow : timestampToBeSend.txt
3- place it in a pool
4- create a simple PHP script that it will run indefinitely

```
while (TRUE) {
// find files that they names are less or equal than current timestamp
// if true ? read the contents, delete the file and send mail
// sleep (DESIRED_TIME);
}
```

This solution works fine from more than 4 years :)

Comment: I ll give it a try and let you know, even if the cronjob will be more suitable for my case! Thanks anyway!